# Rasterio creating composite/stack much larger than the individual bands

Tags: python, raster, gdal, rasterio

I am using rasterio to create a stack of eight bands and each individual band is about 1GB, but when it's stacking them the output (with a lzw compression) is a tif that's over 53GB! This seems huge to me. Anyone know if this is normal?

```
def stack_bands(list_of_rasterio_bands, temp_dir, outputname, output_ext):
    # this will stack bands in the order they are in the list, returns a rasterio object of what was created
    print("[INFO] creating {}".format(outputname))

    composite_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, outputname+output_ext)

    arr_stack = []
    for band in list_of_rasterio_bands:
        band_arr = band.read(1, masked=True)
        arr_stack.append(band_arr)

    out_meta = list_of_rasterio_bands[0].meta.copy()
    out_meta.update({"count": len(list_of_rasterio_bands),
                     "nodata": -10000,
                     "compress": 'lzw'})

    with rasterio.open(composite_path, "w", **out_meta, BIGTIFF="IF_SAFER") as dest:
        for band_nr, src in enumerate(arr_stack, start=1):
            dest.write(src, band_nr)
    print("[INFO] {} saved".format(outputname))

    return rasterio.open(composite_path)
```

Comment: What compression is used in the source data? Adding data into compressed tiff is also sometimes inefficient. Test that by creating a copy of your 8-band image with gdal_translate.

Comment: the separate bands also each have an lzw compression on them

Comment: What does gdalinfo say about the compression of your output? Are you sure you are stacking the data correctly? Have you tried using a predictor to tune the compression? Is there any debugging output in your terminal?

Comment: Please try to make the copy with gdal_translate. Check also image sizes in pixels (width x height) and pixel size.

Comment: What happens with masked=False?

Comment: I added some of the gdal info in a comment to an answer below, but to summarize those questions. I am using LZW compression, I am pretty sure I am stacking correctly, everything looks good visually and I don't get any errors. The pixel size is the same in the sacked image and the original tifs. I think I would want to keep masked=True so it knows what the nodata values are? If I understand right?

Answer (score 0):

Check what is the resolution of your data (Uint8, Uint16, Float32, etc).
If the original files are Uint8 and when passing through your function they are converted to Float32 (some libraries do that), that would explain such huge file.

Run gdalinfo on the 1 GB rasters and see the band type. Then check the type the band when opened with rasterio io (band_arr inside the for loop).

Hope that helps.

J.

Comment: gdalinfo on one of the single bands: 
Size is 38275, 45524
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Band 1 Block=38275x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-10000

Comment: gdalinfo on the stacked raster:
Size is 38275, 45524 
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL. 
And each band in the stack has this information:
Band 1 Block=38275x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-10000,
Band 2 Block=38275x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=-10000, 
Band3 - Band8 same as band2 's info

Comment: and finally the rasterio .meta info on the stacked raster is {'driver': 'GTiff', 'dtype': 'int16', 'nodata': -10000.0, 'width': 38275, 'height': 45524, 'count': 8, 'crs': CRS.from_epsg(32759), 'transform': Affine(0.5, 0.0, 564791.5,
       0.0, -0.5, 5152195.0)}